Handling "Requested the number of rows for section (-1)" Error with RxDataSources's RxTableViewSectionedReloadDataSource
I am developing an iOS application using Swift and RxSwift, specifically utilizing RxTableViewSectionedReloadDataSource for managing my UITableView data bindings. I am not using DataSourceDelegate. Instead, I manage data reactively. Occasionally, when my data source temporarily becomes empty, I encounter a crash with the following error message:
Assertion failure in NSInteger
_UITableViewRowDataNumberOfRowsInSection(UITableViewRowData *__unsafe_unretained, NSInteger)(), 
UITableViewRowData.m:1761

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception:
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Requested the number of rows for section (-1) which is out of bounds.'

This error appears to happen when I try to refresh or scroll the UITableView. How can I handle or prevent this exception from occurring when my section list is empty or when there are rapid updates to the data source?
Additionally, I'm experiencing this issue when the application first opens and the user taps on the "Breaking" tab in the tab bar twice in quick succession. This leads to the same crash with the 'out of bounds' error. How can I prevent this crash from happening during these interactions?
I have implemented a reactive data binding using RxSwift's RxTableViewSectionedReloadDataSource to manage data in a UITableView. Here’s how I bind the data to the table view:
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        registerTableViewCell()
        getSectionCount()
        prepareAdvertorialAd()
        bindViewModel()
    }

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        tabBarController?.delegate = self
        if let isLoading = try? viewModel?.showLoading.value(), !StaticValues.backFromExtraCard && viewModel?.breakingList.value.isEmpty == true && !isLoading {
            viewModel?.getBreaking(url: Constants.breakingPageUrl, tableView: tableView)
        }
//        if !StaticValues.backFromExtraCard && viewModel?.breakingList.value.isEmpty == true && {
//            viewModel?.getBreaking(url: Constants.breakingPageUrl, tableView: tableView)
//            // bindViewModel()
//        }
        prepareAdvertorialAd()
    }

private func bindViewModel() {
        viewModel?.breakingList
            .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] _ in
                self?.getSectionCount()
                self?.tableView.reloadData()
            })
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)

        viewModel?.breakingList
            .bind(to: tableView.rx.items(dataSource: breakingDataSource()))
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)

        viewModel?
            .webUrlBreaking
            .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] url in
                guard let self = self else { return }
                DmpManager.shared.logPageView(className: self.theClassName, url: url, title: Constants.breakingPageName)
                AnalyticsHelper.shared.sendAnalyticsEvents(data: self.prepareAnalyticsData())
            })
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
}

private func registerTableViewCell() {
        tableView.rx.setDelegate(self).disposed(by: disposeBag)
        tableView.registerCell(cell: AdvertorialADTVCell.self)
        tableView.registerCell(cell: BreakingContentCell.self)
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
    }

    func getSectionCount() {
        viewModel?
            .breakingList
            .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] data in
                guard let self = self else { return }
                guard data.count > 0 else { return }

                self.totalSectionCount = data.reduce(0) { total, sectionModel in
                    total + sectionModel.items.count
                }

                // self.tableView.reloadData()
            }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }

func tableView(_: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        guard let breakingList = viewModel?.breakingList.value,
              indexPath.section < breakingList.count,
              indexPath.row < breakingList[indexPath.section].items.count
        else {
            return 0
        }
        let height = viewModel?.breakingList.value[indexPath.first!].estimatedHeight
        let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width

        switch breakingList[indexPath.first!].items.first {
        case .advertorialAdItem:
            if nativeAdv.image(forKey: "CreativeSourceImage") != nil {
                return screenWidth * 0.78 + 28
            } else {
                return 0
            }
        default:
            return height ?? UITableView.automaticDimension
        }
    }

    func tableView(_: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard indexPath.section >= 0, indexPath.row >= 0 else {
            print("Invalid indexPath in willDisplay: Section \(indexPath.section), Row \(indexPath.row).")
            return
        }

        cellHeightsDictionary[indexPath.cacheKey] = cell.frame.size.height
    }

    func tableView(_: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        guard indexPath.section >= 0, indexPath.row >= 0 else {
            print("Invalid indexPath in estimatedHeightForRowAt: Section \(indexPath.section), Row \(indexPath.row).")
            return 0 // Hatalıysa 0 yükseklik döndür.
        }
        return cellHeightsDictionary[indexPath.cacheKey] ?? 0
    }

private func breakingDataSource() -> RxTableViewSectionedReloadDataSource<BreakingSectionModel> {
        return RxTableViewSectionedReloadDataSource<BreakingSectionModel>(
            configureCell: { [weak self] dataSource, tableView, indexPath, _ in
                guard let self = self else { return UITableViewCell() }

                guard indexPath.section >= 0,
                      indexPath.section < dataSource.sectionModels.count,
                      indexPath.row >= 0,
                      indexPath.row < dataSource.sectionModels[indexPath.section].items.count
                else {
                    print("Invalid indexPath: Section \(indexPath.section), Row \(indexPath.row).")
                    return UITableViewCell()
                }

                switch dataSource[indexPath] {
                case .advertorialAdItem:
                    if let cache = self.adCellDic[indexPath[0]] as? AdvertorialADTVCell {
                        return cache
                    }
                    let cell = tableView.cellWithIdentifier(cell: AdvertorialADTVCell.self, for: indexPath)
                    cell.nativeAdv = self.nativeAdv
                    self.adCellDic[indexPath[0]] = cell
                    return cell
                case let .contentListSectionItem(control):
                    let cell = tableView.cellWithIdentifier(cell: BreakingContentCell.self, for: indexPath)

                    let contents = Utils.instance.getDataSource(dataSource: control)
                    cell.clickCellType = "Son dakika Görünüm"
                    cell.rootVC = self
                    cell.data.accept(contents)
                    cell.delegate = self
                    return cell
                }

            }
        )
    }

extension BreakingVC: UITabBarControllerDelegate {
    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect _: UIViewController) {
        StaticValues.backFromExtraCard = false

        if tabBarController.selectedIndex == 1 {
            viewModel?.getBreaking(url: Constants.breakingPageUrl, tableView: tableView)
            tableView.scroll(to: .top, animated: true)
        }

        // Anasayfa tab tıklandığında utm source istenen şekilde eklemek için
        if tabBarController.selectedIndex == 0 {
            DmpManager.shared.logPageView(className: theClassName, url: Constants.hurriyetWebUrl, title: Constants.homePageName, utmSource: Constants.homePageUtm)
        }
    }
}

final class BreakingVM: BaseVM {
    var repo: BreakingRepository?
    // sectionList will unuse for a while.
    //var sectionList = BehaviorRelay<[BreakingSectionModel]>(value: [])
    var breakingList = BehaviorRelay<[BreakingSectionModel]>(value: [])
    var sections: [BreakingSectionModel] = []
    var itemCount: Int = 1
    var goToPageDetail = PublishSubject<SwitchToNewsDetailModel>()
    var webUrlBreaking = PublishSubject<String>()

    /* Additionally, the getBreaking function wasn’t escaping before, I added its previous version at the bottom of the code. I tried making it escaping as a solution. */

    func getBreaking(url: String, completionClosure: @escaping (_ res: [BreakingSectionModel]) -> Void) {
        var newsList = [SwitchToNewsDetailModel]()

        showLoading.onNext(true)
        repo?.getBreaking(url: url)
            .subscribe(onNext: { [self] response in
                self.sections = []
                var dataSources = [DataSource]()
                response.superContent?.template?.regions?.forEach { region in
                    region.controls?.forEach { control in
                        if let dataSource = control.dataSource {
                            dataSources.append(dataSource)
                        }
                    }
                }

                for dataSource in dataSources {
                    itemCount = dataSource.count ?? 1
                    var newsArray = [GoToNewsDetailModel]()

                    dataSource.contents?.forEach { item in
                        newsArray.append(GoToNewsDetailModel(id: item.id,
                                                             url: item.url,
                                                             title: item.title,
                                                             contentType: item.contentType))
                    }
                    newsList.append(SwitchToNewsDetailModel(id: "",
                                                            newsArray: newsArray,
                                                            cellType: "Son dakika Görünüm"))

                    let items = BreakingSectionItem.contentListSectionItem(control: dataSource)
                    let section = BreakingSectionModel.contentListSection(items: [items])
                    sections.append(section)
                }

                StaticValues.newsDetailDataBreaking = newsList
                breakingList.accept(sections)
                self.showLoading.onNext(false)
                self.webUrlBreaking
                    .onNext(
                        response
                            .superContent?
                            .properties?
                            .filter { $0.ixName == "WebUrl" }
                            .first?.value ?? ""
                    )
                completionClosure(sections)
            })
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
}

class BaseVM {
    let showLoading = BehaviorSubject<Bool>(value: false)
}

// And also, this method is a generic type func. So, 'dequeueReusableCell' is already used inside this func. 
func cellWithIdentifier<T: UITableViewCell>(cell _: T.Type, for indexPath: IndexPath) -> T {
        guard let genericCell = dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: T.className, for: indexPath) as? T else {
            TempLogManager.shared.error("Could not dequeue cell with identifier: \(T.className) for indexPath: \(indexPath)")
            fatalError("Could not dequeue cell with identifier: \(T.className) for indexPath: \(indexPath)")
        }
        return genericCell
    }


// OLD getBreaking func.
func getBreaking(url: String, tableView: UITableView) {
        var newsList = [SwitchToNewsDetailModel]()

        showLoading.onNext(true)
        repo?.getBreaking(url: url)
            .subscribe(onNext: { [self] response in
                self.showLoading.onNext(false)
                self.sections = []
                var dataSources = [DataSource]()
                response.superContent?.template?.regions?.forEach { region in
                    region.controls?.forEach { control in
                        if let dataSource = control.dataSource {
                            dataSources.append(dataSource)
                        }
                    }
                }

                for dataSource in dataSources {
                    itemCount = dataSource.count ?? 1
                    var newsArray = [GoToNewsDetailModel]()

                    dataSource.contents?.forEach { item in
                        newsArray.append(GoToNewsDetailModel(id: item.id, url: item.url, title: item.title, contentType: item.contentType))
                    }
                    newsList.append(SwitchToNewsDetailModel(id: "", newsArray: newsArray, cellType: "Son dakika Görünüm"))

                    let items = BreakingSectionItem.contentListSectionItem(control: dataSource)
                    let section = BreakingSectionModel.contentListSection(items: [items])
                    sections.append(section)
                }

                StaticValues.newsDetailDataBreaking = newsList
                tableView.scroll(to: .top, animated: true)
                breakingList.accept(sections)
                self.webUrlBreaking
                    .onNext(
                        response
                            .superContent?
                            .properties?
                            .filter { $0.ixName == "WebUrl" }
                            .first?.value ?? ""
                    )
            })
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }


Additionally, I have added safety checks in the data source to handle cases when the index path might be out of the valid range, especially when the sectionList is empty, but the return block isn’t even executing.
I was expecting the table view to handle empty sections gracefully, preventing any crashes when the data source becomes temporarily empty or when the sections update rapidly. However, I still encounter a crash when the sections list is empty and an interaction (like a scroll) occurs. The crash points to an 'out of bounds' error when requesting the number of rows for a section.

Often when I see problems with data sources, it's because the section model is defined incorrectly. Please post the definition of TemporaryExtraSectionModel...

Based on the information provided, I think your problem is with the .filter { !$0.isEmpty } line.
If there are no items, you need to let the table view know, otherwise it won't update properly.

How do I let tableView know after filter when sectionList is empty? This is actually the part I can't do.

Just remove the filter. That way the table view will receive the empty array and thus know that the section list is empty.

Can I send you all the code? I'm still experiencing the same issue.

Additionally, I'm experiencing this issue when the application first opens and the user taps on the "Breaking" tab in the tab bar twice in quick succession. This leads to the same crash with the 'out of bounds' error. How can I prevent this crash from happening during these interactions?

I have updated the code in my question, could you please take another look? Thank you.

Can you post enough code so it compiles? What are the the types of showLoading, breakingList, getBreaking(url:tableView:) etcetera? That last one seems especially problematic to me.

In looking closer at your code, there are a few fundamental problems with it... For example it looks like you are caching the individual cells of the table view. Instead just use the dequeReusableCell method of the table view and let the table view handle the caching.

I made the additions to the code based on your requests. I added getBreaking, breakingList, and showLoading.

Additionally, since you mentioned the cache, I also added the cellWithIdentifier method to the code.

I know I mentioned this before... Most of the time that I see these sorts of errors, it's because the Section model was defined wrong. You don't show how that was defined. I also see that you are calling reloadData() on your table view. Don't do that, the data source will reload as needed. Try to reduce the amount of code in the question to just the stuff that has to do with the table view. You have a lot of extra code in there and are missing critical bits.
